# Modifying the user agent header in a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-headers, google-chrome-app, user-agent

I want to add something to the user agent header in a chrome kiosk app. The problem is that the api for modifying user agent headers is only available for chrome extensions(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), but not for chrome apps. If I try to use javascript to modify the user agent header with **defineGetter**(see code), it modifies the complete user agent header, but I only want to add something extra to the user agent header. What can I do?

code:

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () {
    return "test"
});
navigator.__defineGetter__('appName', function () {
    return "test"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for the problem, the webview tag has an option to override the user agent. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-setUserAgentOverride